# How does the tuning of fermi energy/level in semiconductors via doping and other factors affect the semiconductor's performance or properties?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, material-science

I was watching one of my lectures from my material science and engineering degree, and the lecturer mentioned by adjusting the doping and operating temperature of a semiconductor , the fermi level could be altered due to the presence of donor and acceptor states. This I understand. However, from my understanding the fermi energy/level is simply the hypothetical energy level at which the probability of it being occupied if it were an actual state is 0.5. So I don't understand the importance of the fermi level besides its significance in the mathematical equations.

i.e. What is the actual physical significance of the fermi level or is it a mathematical tool?

and why is tuning it important to a semiconductor's performance?

I apologise if this is not the right stackexchange site for this question and thank you for any of your help in advance. :)

Comment: Changing where the Fermi energy sits in the gap  (and the dopant levels) makes major differences in electron vs hole carrier concentrations, allowing one to have semiconductor devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the Fermi energy is the highest occupied energy level at $0$K, where-as the Fermi level/chemical potential, $\mu$, is the quantity you have described. At $0$K the Fermi energy =  chemical potential, but at higher temperatures there is no sharply defined cut-off and we do indeed have to define the chemical potential as the energy level with a 50% chance of being occupied according to the Fermi-Dirac distribution

\begin{equation}
f(E) = \frac{1}{\exp{\left(\frac{-(E - \mu)}{k_{B}T}\right)} + 1}.
\end{equation}

So why is either concept useful? Well as a very simple example, if the chemical potential is in the semiconductor band gap and we are at low temperatures, then there is only a small chance that the electrons from the valence band can be excited to the conduction band and, hence, the material will have a very low conductivity. By tuning the chemical potential by doping, we can increase the chance of a valence electron being excited and improve the electrical conductivity of the material.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, would the fermi level as a result shift down towards the valence band at higher temperatures for p type semiconductor?

Comment: The Fermi-level would be closer to the valence in a p-type semiconductor than in one without any doping, yes. This is since the p-type dopants are electron acceptors, resulting in a higher concentration of mobile holes in the valence band.